# when I plot,it show TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

Tags: python, matplotlib

my code:   macroeconomics=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\champion\Desktop\haha\maroeconomics.csv",
    encoding="big5",skiprows=[0,1,2,3],names=["year","industry","money"])

```
data=macroeconomics[["industry","money"]].dropna()
year={"year":macroeconomics["year"]}
year_frame=DataFrame(year).dropna().drop_duplicates()
finish_year=year_frame.reindex(range(151),method="ffill")#handle data

total=pivoted["industry"]+pivoted["sevice_industry"]+pivoted["agruiculture"]
pivoted["agruiculture_ratio"]=pivoted["agruiculture"]/total
pivoted["industry_ratio"]=pivoted["industry"]/total
pivoted["sevice_industry_ratio"]=pivoted["sevice_industry"]/total

plt.figure((15,8))
pivoted["agruiculture"].plot()#I don't know why I can't plot.
pivoted["agruiculture_ratio"]
year
1981    0.059519
1982    0.062761
1983    0.060052
1984    0.053657
1985    0.050128

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-658c446042bc> in <module>()
----> 1 plt.figure((15,8))
      2 str(pivoted["agruiculture_ratio"]).plot()

D:\Anocada2\envs\python3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in     figure(num, figsize, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, frameon, FigureClass, **kwargs)
    508             num = allnums[inum]
    509     else:
--> 510         num = int(num)  # crude validation of num argument
    511 
    512     figManager = _pylab_helpers.Gcf.get_fig_manager(num)
```

Comment: Please include the **full traceback** so we can see where this error occurs and how Python reached that line.

Comment: ok ~~~I edit it again.

Comment: Seems explicit enough, plt.figure() expects an int or a string and not a tuple. Have you considered reading the doc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of setting the [figure size](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure) in matplotlib is

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
```

Putting `plt.figure((15,8))` instead lets the tuple be interpreted as the figure number which cannot work.